# How can I access the assembly's id within a file that is filtered?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have multiple assemblies that looks like:

```
<assembly>
<id>component-000</id>
<fileSet>
    <directory>src/main/assembly</directory>
    <outputDirectory>/${assembly.outputrootdirectory}</outputDirectory>
    <filtered>true</filtered>
</fileSet>
</assembly>
```

As well I have a file that gets included into all assemblies within which i want to include the id (component-000 in this case).

`...
component-id:${id}
...`

I've tried ${assembler.id}, ${assembly.id} ${id} etc all of which have yielded various fail.  Any thoughts?  Also releated, if anyone knows how to potentially dump/print the available properties?

Answer (score 0):

I want to do something similar.  I have a component I want to share between multiple assemblies.  I planned to use the assembly's ID as a directory name, e.g.

```
<fileset>
    <directory>${project.build.directory}/${assemblyId}</directory>
    ....
</fileset>
```

After trying both `${assembly.id}` and `${assemblyId}` with no success, I took a quick look at the code for version 2.3 of the plugin.  I found the code that interpolates other properties (project, filter, env etc.) but it doesn't seem to consider properties in the assembly.  There are a couple of JIRA issues that seem related: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-445 and http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-436.

For my use case, this means I need to duplicate the `<fileset>` block I wanted to share in each assembly.  Or, I could configure the assembly plugin to have multiple executions, each one loading a different filter file.  I'll probably choose the former since I don't have a lot of config to duplicate.